# return and process request in background in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, swagger

I have a function which processes a file data which is passed from swagger. But when file size is more then it take longer to response and request is timed out.

```
def func():
    file = request.files['fileName']
    file_data = file.read().splitlines()
    <read file and process each line>
    return 'File processed'
```

Now I want to just return that file is uploaded, with 201 and then processing should keep happening  in background.

something like this:

```
def func():
    try:
       file = request.files['fileName']
       file_data = file.read().splitlines()
       if file_data:
          return "File uploaded successfully"
     finally:
        <read file and process each line>
```

This is something I was trying.

Can I get some suggestions or if there is any better solution than this. 
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you need a distributed task queue such as [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Is there any other lightweight lib?

Comment: there's [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/) - although I haven't used it personally. There is also the option to fork a new process to complete the task with subprocess.Popen, which is a python build-in module. This might be ok for a small project, but won't scale well.

Comment: I finally did this with a single thread.